# How to declare folder name as global

Tags: python, python-2.7

Following code shows first step where i have to declare output folder as global so that later outputs can be saved in it as well. Right now I am getting an error at output folder string r'optfile/ras1'. Any help how to correctly store files in output folder and declare it as global would be appreciative.

```
import arcpy
import os
import pythonaddins

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
month = now.month
year = now.year

optfile = "C:/temp/"+str(year)+"_"+str(month)

class DrawRectangle(object):
"""Implementation for rectangle_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 1
        self.shape = 'Rectangle'
        os.makedirs(optfile)        

    def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    """Occurs when the rectangle is drawn and the mouse button is released.
        The rectangle is a extent object."""

        extent = rectangle_geometry
        arcpy.Clip_management(r'D:/test', "%f %f %f %f" %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax), r'optfile/ras1', "#", "#", "NONE")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Define what you mean by a 'session'; bash script, terminal session, Windows click-fest?

Comment: Total of 5 sequential steps during a single session. These are separate steps (output of one used as input to next) but output of all steps should go to a single folder created in the beginning.

Comment: I am not asking you how many steps, I am asking what a 'session' means. Is it a python script? Are you running a web server?

Comment: Running automated tools developed using python Add-In

Comment: Some code examples would help understanding your problem

Comment: @Ibe: A python add-in to *what*. The important part here is: how are the python scripts run?

Comment: This is an ArcGIS add-in, and the question has been [cross-posted to GIS.se](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49132/how-to-declare-folder-name-as-global), although the part that isn't working is clearly a simple logic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you mean that the value `r'optfile/ras1'` doesn't use your `optfile` variable. That's because Python does not magically read your mind and replace parts of strings that happen to match a variable name.

You have to use the `optfile` variable explicitly, by concatenating it with the `/ras1` part:

```
    arcpy.Clip_management(
        r'D:/test',
        "%f %f %f %f" %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax),
        optfile + '/ras1', "#", "#", "NONE")
```

or, better yet, use the `os.path.join()` function to take care of the path separators for you:

```
import os.path

# ...

    arcpy.Clip_management(
        r'D:/test',
        "%f %f %f %f" %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax),
        os.path.join(optfile, 'ras1'), "#", "#", "NONE")
```

Note that your problem has nothing to do with global variables; this applies to wherever your variable that you want to concatenate comes from.

Comment: Thanks. I posted only one script above where 'optfile' folder created. Second step is to use another script but I want to use same 'optfile' to save output in it. Now I want to declare 'optfile' globally, which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: @Ibe: Back to square one. How is the other script run? Can you use `import otherscript; otherscript.main()`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Let me try to explain it:
These scripts are run in the form of tools inside ArcGIS environment. Second script is also a tool which upon click do processing based on inputs in the display and should save output to 'optfile' created during first tool run.

Comment: @Ibe: can you use command line arguments? `python yourscript.py "optfile"`?

Comment: Command line use would hinder automation of these scripts and I don't exactly know how that would be included in python Add-In.